# Local user on PC1 as an admin on PC2

Tags: domain, users, local, user-permissions

This is the scenario:

PC1, joined to a domain, has a local user (localuser1)

PC2, joined to the same domain

Is there a way to make localuser1 be an admin on PC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik no.
A workaround is creating the same localuser1 on the PC2 machine, let the user set up the same password, and then add it to the PC2's Administrators group.